# How Do We Try Freeform Multi-Window Mode on the Android N Developer Preview?

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

The [N Developer Preview documentation](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/multi-window.html) cites a freeform multi-window mode option:

> Manufacturers of larger devices can choose to enable freeform mode, in which the user can freely resize each activity. If the manufacturer enables this feature, the device offers freeform mode in addition to split-screen mode.

The docs also suggest that you should test your app in freeform multi-window mode.

However, the two devices that I loaded the N Developer Preview images on (Nexus 6 and Nexus 9) use the split-screen approach for multi-window support.

Is there a way to get freeform mode going on something?

- Another device? (e.g., Pixel C)
- Settings > Developer Options? (I didn't see anything obvious for this, but I may have missed it)
- A specific emulator configuration?
- Some `adb` command?
- A magic spell, cast by [speaking a command backwards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zatanna)?

I am guessing that we might see some hardware that supports freeform mode natively in late May, but I'm just seeing if there's an option to try it out now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Freeform multi-window is not available in Dev Preview 1 - only split-screen multi-window.

Comment: Ah, well, I figured that it was worth a shot. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1):

[Lifehacker has instructions](http://lifehacker.com/heres-what-freeform-windows-in-android-n-look-like-and-1766353465) to enable Freeform Multi-Window Mode. It works in the "Android N final SDK". Here's the essence (with the curly quotes fixed and tips added):

1. Create an x86 emulator AVD with Android N, for a tablet like Nexus 10.
   **Tip:** Name all your AVDs like "24 N Nexus 10". Starting with the Android API version gets the AVD Manager to sort them helpfully.
   **Tip:** Enable "Multi-Core CPU" with 2 CPUs.
   **Tip:** Set it to open in "Landscape" orientation.
   **Tip:** Don't "Enable Device Frame" unless you have a large monitor. You need the space for the content.
2. Start the AVD. Wait for it to boot up.
3. Use adb and a terminal to run these commands:

   - `adb shell`
   - `su`
   - `setenforce 0`
   - `settings put global enable_freeform_support 1`
   - `cd /data/local/tmp`
   - `mkdir permissions`
   - `cd permissions`
   - `cp -a /system/etc/permissions/* ./`
   - `sed -e "s/live_wallpaper/freeform_window_management/" android.software.live_wallpaper.xml >freeform.xml`
   - `mount --bind . /system/etc/permissions`
   - Wait a couple seconds
   - `stop`
   - Wait a couple more seconds
   - `start`

The Lifehacker page also has instructions to enable Freeform Multi-Window Mode on an Android N device.

Answer (score 0):

Multi-window is not available, split screen multiwindow is supporting.

In Android N, we're introducing a new and much-requested multitasking feature into the platform — multi-window support.

- Users can now pop open two apps on the screen at once.
- On phones and tablets running Android N, users can run two apps
  side-by-side or one-above-the-other in splitscreen mode. Users can
  resize the apps by dragging the divider between them.
- On Android TV devices, apps can put themselves in picture-in-picture
  mode, allowing them to continue showing content while the user
  browses or interacts with other apps.